# How to add custom entries to /etc/hosts with MAMP?

Tags: apache, mamp

I am using MAMP Pro to create and manage custom virtual hosts on my machine. I am finding I need to add the following to my /etc/hosts file to get certain browsers (Chrome) to load faster:

fe80::1%lo0 example.dev

The problem is that MAMP is wiping my customizations out whenever I change anything via the app.

Any ideas how I can keep my customizations?